# Windows: How to be notified when a thread enters/exit "waiting" state?

Tags: windows, multithreading, winapi, callback, synchronization

I'm trying to implement a smarter thread pool. In order to accommodate legacy code, it would be great if I could be notified whenever a pooled thread switches from a waiting state (blocked IO, sleep, synchronization, critical section, etc) and a running state.

I'm looking for an OS API in Windows that gives me one of these options:

- Register a callback that will be called in the context of a pooled thread just before it enters a "waiting" state due to a blocking call, and also just after it resumes from this wait; OR
- Register a synchronization object for each pooled thread, that will be signaled whenever a blocking call starts or ends.

But I cannot change the blocking calls. The application is full of socket reads and writes, file reads and writes, WaitForSingleObject calls, etc. I cannot surround this code with calls to my management code. I also don't want to trap API calls, as that involves a large number of APIs and would require me to interpret parameters and detect which calls are blocking and which are not.

I took a look on [Windows Thread Pool API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686766%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but it doesn't seem to provide such feature. There's an API called [BindIoCompletionCallback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363484(v=vs.85).aspx), but it doesn't provide the required feature.

Is there any API that I might be missing?

Comment: This doesn't exist, nor could you create it.  The app itself would have to co-operate, that will never turn out well.

Comment: Whatever you problem is, this is not going to be the solution

Comment: What Hans and David say.  I would not waste my time on this kind of approach because, even if it could be implemented, the chances of it working in any kind of reliable and predictable way are approx. 0.

Comment: I don't believe there's any way to be notified, but you could poll.